# How secure is the Android app cache?

Tags: android, caching

That is, the locations returned by `getExternalCacheDir()` and `getCacheDir()`.

Can other apps of a certain privilege level access these directories? Does the phone need to be rooted to access these?

What can I store there safely, and what should I avoid storing there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can other apps of a certain privilege level access these directories?

`getExternalCacheDir()` is accessible by any app that holds the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

`getCacheDir()` is accessible only by your app, with the exception being on rooted devices where the user explicitly uses an app that leverages superuser capabilities to access the entire filesystem. However, any app can trigger the system to clear out the cache, so to some extent, any app can have delete privileges for `getCacheDir()`. If that concerns you, use `getFilesDir()`.

> Does the phone need to be rooted to access these?

For `getCacheDir()`, yes (excluding the clear-cache scenario described above). For `getExternalCacheDir()`, no.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Would the directory returned by getCacheDir() be suitable for storing temporary access tokens for a remote API, for example? Or would that be better off stored elsewhere?

Comment: @QuestionAsker: That depends on who you are worried about using those tokens and what the level of risk is if somebody gets those tokens. If you are worried about run-of-the-mill malware apps, and the tokens are not exceptionally valuable, `getCacheDir()` should be fine. If you are worried about the *user* stealing the tokens, do not hold onto them in files, but only hold onto them in RAM, and then recognize that sufficiently dedicated attackers can still get them (e.g., run your app on an emulator, use a kernel debugger).